# Monodevelop doesn't stop on breakpoint

Tags: monodevelop, xamarin.android

I have a problem with MonoDevelop and Mono for Android.
In most of my classes the debugger does not stop when reaching a breakpoint. But in some it does. So I can break at a class where the debugger always stops and from there I can step into the class where it won't stop by itself. So debugging information is there and the debugger is attached correctly.

I have the problem with the emulator and with a physical Android device. Also the Mono for Android samples have this problems.

The classes where the debugger stops and not stops are in the same project, therefore compile settings are the same.

Also the breakpoints that are not working in MonoDevelop look kind of grayed out, like the source is not belonging to the currently debugged application. But as I said before, I can step through exactly this code when stepping in from a class that can be debugged.

I use MonoDevelop 2.8.5 and Mono for Android: 4.0.1.234125318 (Windows 7)

Thanks for your help,

Timo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem, there appears to be an open issue for it ...
http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2196
--Andy

Comment: Thanks for the link to the report. I found out that debugging works with Visual Studio, so I will use this until they come up with a fix.